# Are questions about security courses on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, question-quality

I have been looking for a sort of CBT that covers the web development with a 'hacking'/security focus by addressing a methodology along the lines of:

**a)** covering aspects of web development; and **b)** security - how to build the site **securely** and how we can hack it.

Would this question be off topic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asking for courses is off topic and also too localised.

Any course may be localised in location, but even web-based courses suffer from possibly being time-bound.

We do mention some courses, generally the industry respected, long standing ones, but in general it is just not useful on an SE site to list courses, so a) is not on topic.

B)is actually something that we provide here. Questions on hardening specific platforms or applications are on topic and many have been covered already. Questions on attack and defence are also entirely on topic.

Comment: Thanks @Rory Alsop♦. Much clearer now.